# CakePHP This->render does not load controller

Tags: cakephp

I have a couple of Views that are used in a lot of locations. The view is the same but the controller isn't so I placed .ctp files in the Elements directory and use the following code in the different controllers.

```
$this->render('/Elements/overview');
```

however, I also have some php code that needs to be executed every time the view loads.
So I thought to just create a controller in the Contollers directory named as the view in the Elements directory (overviewController.php) but unfortunately, the code in that controller isn't executed.

Is there a way to do this or am I doing this completely wrong?

**EDIT:** Ok With Dave's advice I copied the overview.ctp file to a new directory called Global. Renamed the controller to GlobalController.php, renamed the class to GlobalController and changed the $this->render. But still, the view is loaded and the controller that I use to render the view is loaded but the GlobalController isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not normal to use elements for your entire view.  Your better off using an actual view file.  Elements are smaller chunks of code to use WITHIN Views.

**Example:**

Create an 'OverviewsController.php' (notice it's PluralController.php).  Within that, create a function:

```
public function overview() {

}
```

To access that function, use the url:  `www.yourdomain.com/overviews/overview`

And the view file for it should be in `Views/Overviews/overview.ctp`

You can then include the Element within the view if it's something you plan on using in many places.

**Edit:**

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted, but you don't need to render an element - just render a view:

```
public function anything() {
    $this->render('/Overviews/overview');
}
```

Comment: I get that, I use that for the normal pages. However this doesn't solve my issue with the views that I want to use more then once with different controllers

Comment: Edited answer to include rendering a view from a different action.